# htaccess to rewrite url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

1. I want the user to write a URL like

   http://www.domain.com/adm/folder/page/somthing/somthing/somthing[...]
2. Then I want to use the URL in my PHP code like I would use this one:

   http://www.domain.com/adm/master.php?f=folder&p=page&otherparam1=somthing&otherparm2=somthing&otherparm3=somthing[...]

This URL give me two main parameters, folder and page, and som other that can variable to be present or not.

3. In my master.php-file I include a php-file based on these parameters:

   ```
   $folder = $_GET['f'];
   $page = $_GET['p'];
   if(empty($page)) {
       $page = 'dashboard';
   }
   $path = $folder.'/'.$page;
   include_once 'pages/'.$path.'.php?otherparm1=somthing&otherparm2=somthing&otherparm3=somthing[...]';
   ```

The otherparam is to be multiple parameters given i the URL.

**How can I show the first URL to the user and use URL number two in the PHP-application? Is htaccess rewrithe right thing to use?**

I have searched the web, but not been able to find a solution.

Comment: don't use vars from http requests in include path, or validate them before it

Comment: I have added a code to check that the file acually exist and that it is on a list with valid files. The user get an error trying to reach other files or somthing that does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you couldn't do it only by .htaccess, because of variable count of parameters.

Add in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This rule will pass all 404 request to index.php and in index.php parse url

```
$parts = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
$folder = $parts[0];
$page = $parts[1];
$otherparm1 = $parts[2];
$otherparm2 = $parts[3];
```

Comment: This might work. I get to include the right php-file, but there is a problem that all files included in the page get the url rewritten. In example the path to the css-files. Is it possible to modify the .htaccess-code so it only rewrithe php-paths?

Comment: This rewrite redirects to index.php only for urls that have no file on server (for 404 errors). Show page html with incorrect urls to css.

Comment: The CSS-files and images does not work on the page. When I check the source code the links to them work, but only after I used the whole URL with the domain and everything. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I finally got it to work. I had to change all css- and script references to have full path. Did it with a simple PHP-code. thanks for all the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ master.php?folder=$1&page=$2&something=$3[...] [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Then you can link the page in like an a href like so:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/adm/folder/page/somthing/somthing/somthing[...]">Link</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not get this to work. Have used Max P´s solution.